# PHP/Javascript to update input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

OK, So not a big HTML or Javascript person. But I am doing what I can to get by.

I am working on a project for a Marine Cadets Explorers Post to create a online database for them to help manage their membership and other functions. In entering their membership records they will have multiple families that will have several kids in the post, so they don't want to have to re-enter their parents records. I wanted to create a drop down box that is populated by a SQL Database lookup (Which I did) and then, if they select a parent from that list, the form will populate, saving the entry.

I only provided a snipped of the HTML, since the form has over 50 fields and for example, I only really need to show one.

So the HTML is below.

```html
<form name="YouthApp" class="form-application" method="post" id="application-form">
   <div style="height:0.20in; left:1.75in; overflow:hidden; padding:2px; position:absolute; top:4.10in; width:1.48in; ">
      <select name="selSupp" style="width:1.46in;">
         <option value="">Existing Supporters</option>
         <?php makeSuppDropdown() ?>
      </select>
   <div style="height:26px; left:0.36in; overflow:hidden; padding:2px; position:absolute; top:4.52in; width:353px; ">
      <input style="height:0.20in; width:3.64in; " name="SuppFirst" required value="<?php if(isset($_POST['SuppFirst'])){ echo $_POST['SuppFirst']; } ?>" maxlength="20" type="text" placeholder="First Name" >
   </div>
   </div>   
</form>
```

It calls a PHP Function that populates the drop down:

```
function makeSuppDropdown() {

   include("dbconnect.php");

   $sql = "SELECT SupporterId, ".
          "CONCAT(LastName, ',', FirstName,' ',MidName,' ',trim(Suffix)) as 'SuppLookup' ".
            "FROM tblsupporters ".
           "ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, MidName, Suffix";

   $sql_result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   $field= mysqli_fetch_fields($sql_result);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
      echo '                    <option value="'.$row['SupporterId'].'" >'.$row['SuppLookup'].'</option>'.chr(10);
   }
}
```

The function provided the following output:

```
<select name="selSupp" style="width:1.46in;">
   <option value="">Existing Supporters</option>
   <option value="32517-02" >Truxton,Karla Andrianne </option>
   <option value="32517-01" >Truxton,Tommie Lee </option>
</select>
```

If the user selects a Parent Supporter then I wanted to start filling in the input fields. This is where I am having a problem.

Here is the PHP/Javacode I am using that is not working:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['selSupp'])) {

   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("SuppFirst").value = "Tommie";
   </script>
   <?php 
    } ?>
```

Now I know that PHP and Javascript don't always play well together, but I'm hoping that there is a solution that will allow me to fill in the fields.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, however, to the best of my knowledge, you want the users after choosing their parents' information, a form appears with filled parents' info and extra fields.
If so, i suggest creating a submit button, since I'm not sure if a drop-down select can be submitted on itself:

```
if ($_POST['sbm']) { //if submit button is pressed
  $option = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['select-name']);
  //Get option from the users
  if ($option == '') { //If $option == '' means if there is no value
    header("Location: this_file.php?error=notselected"); //Redirect to the desired page
    exit();
  }
  else {
    header("Location: this_file.php?error=noerror");
    exit();
  }
}
```

And in the desired page (the page that contains the select form), you add:

```
if (isset($_GET['error'] && !empty($_GET['error'])) { //Check if error parameter exists
  $error = $_GET['error'];
  //Get the error
  switch ($error) {
    case "notselected": echo "<b style=\"color:red;\">Error!</b>"; break;
    case "noerror": echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('input-wanted-to-show').show();});</script>"; break; //Print out the script part that you need or show the hidden input. After this php code, please go to html and add desired input fields.
  }
}
```

Overall, I know you want to submit that select form and add javascript if it is done, so I advice is to add a submit button, add parameter when option is valid, then use $_GET to check the parameter, print out the approriate  tags.

If you still want to keep the select value, use AJAX.
If there is any problem, just comment.

I will be glad to help you figure out!

Comment: did I? I didn't throw any parameter on the URL bar, can you help me point out that?

Comment: Aorry, I forgot to add that there is a submit button on the form, I removed it from the example. I was concentrating on trying to fill the fields with the already provided data.  If the parent is not in the provided list, then they would fill in the fields.

I haven't ever used AJax, so I will have to read up on that and see if it will fill my needs.  Looks like I have some studying to do.

Comment: Same idea @GrumpaTom, if $option == ‘’, then pass a parameter on the url bar and print out the appropriate javascript code. In my example, just change the first case in the switch statement